# Wpf binding columns to list

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm wondering what is the best approach to my problem. I need to generate DataGrid for my data. My data looks like this:

```
Competitor{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Sname {get; set;}
    public List<TimeSpan> Laps {get; set;}
}
```

Name and SName are known from the beggining. When competitors makes circle he gets his Lap TimeSpan.

So, after 5 laps DataGrid should look like this:

```
Name  |  SName  | Lap1  | Lap2  | Lap3  | Lap4  | Lap5
asd   |  dsa    | 1:1:1 | 1:2:1 | 1:0:1 | 1:2:2 | 1:3:1
bbb   |  cccc   | 2:2:2 | 2:1:1 | 1:0:0 | 2:0:0 | 1:2:3
...
```

I checked this approach http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/populating-a-datagrid-with-dynamic-columns-in-a-silverlight-application-using-mvvm/ but it's not exacly what I've expected.

Any idea how to make this done? 
(any other then manually adding column with new lap, it should be automaticly added)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Keep a `DataTable` for your records. Bind this `DataTable` with `DataGrid's` `AutogenerateColumns` to `true`.
2. Change `List<Timespan>` to `ObservableCollection<Timespan>` for Laps.
   `ObservableCollection` fires `CollectionChanged` event when an item is added/removed.
3. Handle `CollectionChanged` event and update `DataTable` with adding more columns.
4. Now, we need to refresh the `DataGrid` otherwise it won't show extra columns added. It will show the new row added but extra columns won't be shown. So, do this :

   ```
       Dgrid1.ItemsSource = null;
       Dgrid1.ItemsSource = oldDataTable.DefaultView;
   ```

Comment: Was thinking about DataTable and because of lack of time will use this approach, so thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you can use ListBox instead of DataGrid. You can do this:

**.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
            <!--Header-->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5 0 0 0">
                <TextBlock Width="100" Text="Name"/>
                <TextBlock Width="100" Text="Sname"/>
                <ListBox x:Name="ListHeader" BorderThickness="0">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Width="100"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>

            <!--List of Competitors-->
            <ListBox x:Name="Mylist">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding Sname}"/>
                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Laps}" BorderThickness="0">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Width="100"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            </ListBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

**.cs

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Competitor> list = new List<Competitor>();
            list.Add(new Competitor { Name = "Renee", Sname = "Lewallen", Laps = new List<TimeSpan> { TimeSpan.Parse("00:10"), TimeSpan.Parse("00:20"), TimeSpan.Parse("00:30") } });
            list.Add(new Competitor { Name = "Barney", Sname = "Fett", Laps = new List<TimeSpan> { TimeSpan.Parse("00:10"), TimeSpan.Parse("00:20"), TimeSpan.Parse("00:30"), TimeSpan.Parse("00:40") } });
            list.Add(new Competitor { Name = "Nelle", Sname = "Butterfield", Laps = new List<TimeSpan> { TimeSpan.Parse("00:10"), TimeSpan.Parse("00:20"), TimeSpan.Parse("00:30"), TimeSpan.Parse("00:40"), TimeSpan.Parse("00:50") } });
            list.Add(new Competitor { Name = "Marc", Sname = "Soriano", Laps = new List<TimeSpan> { TimeSpan.Parse("00:10"), TimeSpan.Parse("00:20") } });
            list.Add(new Competitor { Name = "Cathi", Sname = "Stumpff", Laps = new List<TimeSpan> { TimeSpan.Parse("00:10"), TimeSpan.Parse("00:20"), TimeSpan.Parse("00:30") } });
            list.Add(new Competitor { Name = "Jefferey", Sname = "Hunziker", Laps = new List<TimeSpan> { TimeSpan.Parse("00:10"), TimeSpan.Parse("00:20"), TimeSpan.Parse("00:30") } });
            list.Add(new Competitor { Name = "Berniece", Sname = "Courtney", Laps = new List<TimeSpan> { TimeSpan.Parse("00:10"), TimeSpan.Parse("00:20"), TimeSpan.Parse("00:30") } });

            var LapsCounter = list.Select(w => w.Laps.Count).Max();

            List<string> listH = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= LapsCounter; i++)
            {
                listH.Add("Lap" + i);
            }
            Mylist.ItemsSource = list;
            ListHeader.ItemsSource = listH;

        }

        public class Competitor
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Sname { get; set; }
            public List<TimeSpan> Laps { get; set; }
        }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: it is similar approach to the one I linked in my first post. It looks good, but You loose possibility to easy select or sort by specific lap. Sure it can be overriden but there would be lack of flexibility